# Unable to use the between clause with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to figure out why I am unable to return a list of posts using a where close between.

```
    const posts = await db.post.findAll({
        where: {
            id: {
                [Op.notIn]: [...seenPosts]
            },
            latitude: {
                [Op.between]: [minLat, maxLat]
            },
            longitude: {
                [Op.between]: [minLong, maxLong]
            }
        },
        order: [
            [ sequelize.literal('(select count(*) from like_posts where like_posts.post_id=post.id)'), 'DESC' ],
            [ 'createdAt', 'DESC']
        ],
        limit: 5
    })
```

I am getting returned not a single post. When I remove the where close for Long and Lat I am able to return posts. What might be the problem with the where clause?

The model for Long and Lat is:

```
    longitude: {
        type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,4),
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
```

Thank you for the help on this matter.

Comment: What data do you expect to return?

Comment: Are you searching like 5km/5mile radius or something ?

Comment: Check that your min values are actually less than your max values, since BEWEEN 1 and 10 is not the same as BETWEEN 10 and 1. Also be careful of the calculations around 180 for your lat/longs if you're just doing something like +/- some number, as you need to stay within the range [-180,180]. 
If you're using Postgres, you should probably look at POSTGIS extension.